# For an img element, is there a way to position it like background-position is to a background image?

Tags: html, css

So just a general question. I usually use background-images to display pictures in divs and will use things like background-position to center the image in the div.

Is there a property like this for an img element inside a div? I know object-fit works for both, but it seems like background-position does not which makes sense.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of; is there a specific problem you're trying to address (I realise you specified that this is "*just a general question*")?

Comment: yes here s a lot of way (position:absolute + lelt/top , flexbox + margin, etc)